# Picture 'disappear' without float-property

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to figure out css, one step at a time. Consider the following code:

```html
<header id="main">
    <a href="#" id="title"></a> 
</header>
```

and CSS:

```css
#main{
    height: 220px;
    width: auto;
    border: 2px #000000 solid;
}

#title{
    float: left;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/m9fvwoJ.jpg) no-repeat;
    width: 300px;
    height: 175px;
}
```

If I remove the float-property, the picture 'disappear', and I'm having difficulties understanding why.

Heres is the code in JsFiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/5nWag/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An element automatically becomes a block-level element when its [floated](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats), so your width and height rules are applying and working as you'd expect. Inline elements can't have an explicit width and height, as their content determines the size of their line boxes. Inline elements also cannot have any vertical margin, borders, or padding. The reason the background *disappears* is because your `<a>` has no content and as a result, no dimensions and also because you apparently can't give an `<a>` element a background-image without modifying its display value. If you wrap a `<span>` around it and add content the background-image will be visible:

http://jsfiddle.net/5nWag/8/

Comment: Same behaviour if you have `display:block` instead `float:left` and you remove it: the element dissapears.